# How to retrieve text from selected area as it does TalkBack app

Tags: android, text-to-speech, accessibilityservice

I'm developing a application like TalkBack which will help blind people to surf the internet.
Now I want to retrieve text from selected area like it does TalkBack[image]

This is my Accessibility Service xml config, but I can't select any text in browser and **accessibilityEvent.getText()** always return empty string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <accessibility-service  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:accessibilityFlags = "flagDefault"
    android:description="@string/service_description"/>
```